# AWS RDS Postgres query performance issue

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, query-performance

I have a Postgres database on AWS RDS running on an `m1/small` instance. It has a table with 40 million rows. When I query something like this:

```
select * from business where name = 'Pizza House'
```

It takes a couple of minutes to get a response. What can I do to improve query performance of the database?

Here is the create command used to create this table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.business
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('business_id_seq'::regclass),
  name character varying,
  city character varying,
  state character varying,
  zip character varying,
  is_claimed integer,
  ...,
  ...,
  CONSTRAINT business_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE public.business
  OWNER TO administrator;
```

When I run:

```
explain select * from business where name = 'Pizza House'
```

I get:

```
1, "Seq Scan on business  (cost=0.00..1481123.57 rows=22 width=636)"
2, "  Filter: ((name)::text = 'Pizza House'::text)"
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the `create table` statement for the table in question (including all indexes) and the execution plan generated using `explain (analyze, verbose)`. [**Formatted text**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). [edit] your question. Do **not** post code or additional information in comments

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I just added those details. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you will want to put an `index` on the `name` column.

But as a whole you should read up on indexes. This is a good resource:

http://use-the-index-luke.com/